# How to compare a part of string numerically then output the matched line?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sort

Suppose I have these lines to feed to `awk`:

```
dolly-cabinet-93-red
murfy-swan-96-white
chizzle-rock-115-green
```

How do I select the line cut by `-` whose 3rd column is the largest (numerically) and output the line (preferably using `awk`, but not limited to)?

Somehow the solution I have thinks 96 is the largest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are doing some sort of sorting, and that this sorting is done lexicographically rather than numerically, in which case `96` would be sorted after `115` (since `9` comes after `1`).

---

```
awk -F '-' '$3 > max { max = $3; line = $0 } END { print line }' file
```

For the given data, this will output

```
chizzle-rock-115-green
```

The code compares the third `-`-delimited field to the current largest found number (`max`).  If the field's number is larger, `max` is updated with that number and the current input line is saved in `line`.  At the end, the contents of `line` is printed.

This is slightly quicker than sorting since it's a linear operation (sorting is at best `O(n*log(n))`), but you won't notice a big difference unless you have large amounts of data.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach with `sort` + `head`:

```
sort -t'-' -k3nr file | head -1
```

The output:

```
chizzle-rock-115-green
```